# Determine and prove the nature of $f(x)$

Tags: polynomials

Consider a polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients having the property $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ for every polynomial $g(x)$ with real coefficients. Determine and prove the nature of $f(x)$.

My guess is that $f(x)$ is its own inverse. Could anyone shed some more fire on this for me?

Also, what if $f(x)$ is not its own inverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a constant polynomial for $g$, say $g(x) = g_0$. The given property reads then 
$$ g_0 = g\bigl(f(x)\bigr) = f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) = f(g_0) $$
So, if any $f$ has your property then $f(x) = x$. As this $f = \mathrm{id}$ obviously fulfills $f \circ g = g \circ f$ for any $g$, we see that that $f = \mathrm{id}$ is the only solution.

Comment: does $\mathrm{id}$ mean identity? Like in Abstract Algebra meaning of identity?

Comment: The $\mathrm{id}\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, that is the polynomial $f(x) = x$.

Comment: What is the name of $\mathrm{id}$, so I can look it up, or tell me the name of a book to learn more.

Comment: In this context it is simply the polynomial given by $f(x)=x$.